# Password Recovery

Tags: windows, security, password

Currently we use [Offline NT Password & Registry Editor](http://home.eunet.no/pnordahl/ntpasswd/) for machines we do not have admin passwords for. It is a really nice tool but has some flaws. Is there something better/more modern?

Comment: What flaws have you found? I've used it for years and not had a problem. I ask this genuinely out of interest.

Comment: Under the FAQ they cite EFS and AD PDC as being unrecoverable. While I love this tool for workstations, these other two can create a problem if you are taking over.

Comment: Well the above comments are by design, if you have ever played with the other features such as setting passwords, enabling accounts, etc., it works probably 60% of the time. Obviously the best thing to do is just blank admin pass and restart. That would be a cool automated tool.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've had success with OphCrack

http://ophcrack.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 2):

Before it was pulled, l0phtcrack was the way to go.  L0pht went commercial and the tool was pulled.  ophcrack is a "branch" of this and will provide you with what you need (see Kenvin Dente's answer for linky).

This may or may not apply to your situation, but to *avoid* this issue, the Local Administrator account is set to a different password, and is never given to anyone for any reason.  So, even if the machine is disconnected from the network, and you've used up your 15 cached attempts (the default), you can still get in and affect changes as needed.  Users that need special privs (when it's absolutely required because the program's concept of security is botched) we grant them "Power User", etc.

Answer (score 0):

Kryptos Logic Kon Boot works well. No need to overwrite passwords, but it can do it as well.